# iText7 License Key in Azure with no file path

Tags: itext, itext7

Loading a license file in iText7 is done as follows:
LicenseKey.LoadLicenseFile("path/to/itextkey.json");

What do you do if your application is in Azure and you do not have a file path?

I tried converting the license key .json file into a memory stream and using that as the argument, but that results in a null reference error.

Update: In order to get the above to work as a stream I needed to use a different licensing dll. The new one is iText.lisensing.base 4.1.0.  After changing that I ran into a new issue requiring one of two additional dlls one of which was "bouncy-castle-adapter" this is progress, but I need to find the new documentation.

Comment: you can find license installation instructions [here](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/installation-guidelines/installing-the-itext-license-key-and-license-key-library-for-java-and-net).

Comment: bouncy-castle-adapter can be found on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter) or [Artifactory](https://repo.itextsupport.com/ui/repos/tree/General/nuget/itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter).

Comment: André, thanks for posting.  I have seen and read that documentation several times.  As you might see by my post I am acknowledging what is written there and asking for a better way. It is neither secure nor industry standard to include secret information in plain text readable files. Since posting this I have succeeded in placing the contents of the license key file in a secure location and reading it into the above method using a memory stream.

Comment: ah, sorry! I didn't quite understood your problem then! thanks for clarifying.